# ffmpeg At least one output file must be specified error

Tags: ffmpeg

How can i fix this ;( help me....
it works well if i tpye only "**'ffmpeg -i ' + video_path + ' -q:v 2 -f image2 ' + frame_path + '\image_%6d.jpg'**" on prompt with specific path name.
but it doesn't work in .py (i used code in .py-> **os.system('ffmpeg -i ' + video_path + ' -q:v 2 -f image2 ' + frame_path + '\image_%6d.jpg'**)

'''
ffmpeg version 4.3.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 10.2.1 (GCC) 20200726
configuration: --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsrt --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libgsm --enable-librav1e --disable-w32threads --enable-libmfx --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt --enable-amf
libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000002629ef05540] stream 0, timescale not set
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'E:\dataset\Videos\Arrest\Arrest007_x264.mp4':
Metadata:
major_brand     : isom
minor_version   : 512
compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
track           : 0
artist          :
album           :
date            : 0
genre           :
lyrics          :
title           :
encoder         : Lavf56.36.100
Duration: 00:01:44.84, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1499 kb/s
Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 320x240 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 1387 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
Metadata:
handler_name    : VideoHandler
Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 105 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
handler_name    : SoundHandler
Stream #0:2: Video: png, rgb24(pc), 58x38 [SAR 304:261 DAR 16:9], 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc (attached pic)
At least one output file must be specified
'''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make use of helpful (& more secure) built-in packages/functions:

```py
from os import path
import subprocess as sp

sp.run(['ffmpeg','-i', video_path, 
                 '-q:v','2','-f','image2',
                 path.join(frame_path,'image_%6d.jpg')])
```

I suspect your call went nuts because of unescaped backslashes in the file paths. `subprocess.run` essentially avoids that nastiness from making a system call.